# How to subtract two surfaces in GNUPLOT?

Tags: plot, 3d, gnuplot, surface, subtraction

I would like to import two CSV files in GNUPLOT. 
So far so good.
This works very well. But I would like to subtract the two surfaces and get the difference (distance) between the two surfaces.
I wanted to link a picture, but this did not work because I do not have 10 reputations. If interested on the plot please send me an e-mail.
I searched on Google and read a lot of tutorials. But I did not find the right one. 
For reading the data and plot it following code is used:

```
cd 'd:\temp\ '
set datafile separator ";"    
set datafile commentschars "#!%"
set dgrid3d splines
set dgrid3d 30,30 qnorm 2
set pm3d
set contour base
set cntrparam levels incr 85,1,95
set cntrlabel start 2 font ",7"
set contour both
set zrange [85:94]
set view 0,0
set palette rgbformulae 22,13,-31
splot "Alt_220_RL_50C.csv" u 1:2:3 with lines,"220_RL_50C.csv" u 1:2:3 with lines
```

I would like to subtract the two plotted surfaces. For the values that are not available I would try an "if then" solution. 
What would be the best way to solve the issue?

Comment: This can be done with `paste`. Once you have all the data on the same file you can subtract the two columns of interest. There are several examples of how to do this here in SO. In your case, assuming that your data files are commensurate, you'd do something like `splot "< paste Alt_220_RL_50C.csv 220_RL_50C.csv" u 1:2:($3-$6) ...`. If you don't have access to `paste` then find an alternative solution (e.g. write a python script to do it). If your data files are not commensurate then it would be more complicated since you'll probably need interpolation. If that's the case, ask another question

Comment: Hi Miguel,
the data files are not commensurate.
I think i will try to interpolate with dgri3d and write to an external file.
Afterwards with the same grid for the data i am able to subtract.
Kind Regards
Markus

Comment: Yes, that sounds like a workable solution. Another option is that if you can work with fitted surfaces for which you know an analytical form you can subtract the fitted expressions.